# Como agrupar radio buttons

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

Olá,

Estou querendo fazer uma forma que esses radio buttons fiquem com o mesmo name dentro de um form, mas que sejam marcados por pergunta.

Pois vou enviar este formulário para um PHP e pegar lá ele como array, essas perguntas vão vir do banco de dados, portanto não coloco nomes diferentes pois pode ser que tenha 2 perguntas ou 30 perguntas, não há como eu deixar predefinido no PHP quantas questão e quais os nomes vão vir pelo POST.

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pergunta 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pergunta 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alguém me ajuda, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir o name como um array, ficaria assim:

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pergunta 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[1]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[1]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[1]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[1]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[1]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pergunta 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[2]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[2]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[2]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[2]">
      <input type="radio" name="resposta[2]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

e no seu php:

```
foreach ($_POST['resposta'] as $resposta) {
    // código
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de atribuir um value no input!